# Converting Curl GET request to Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, curl

I'm trying to replicate a Curl request to download a PDF in Ajax.  The Curl requests are explained in the PDF Filler docs [here](http://developers.pdffiller.com/#api-client-libraries).  The following Curl request successfully yields a response of the file content:

```
curl -X "GET" "https://api.pdffiller.com/v1/fillable_template/DOCUMENT_ID/download" -H "Authorization: Bearer API_KEY_FROM_STEP1"
```

I've tried the following Ajax:

```
$.ajax({
    method: 'GET',
    url: 'https://api.pdffiller.com/v1/fillable_template/DOCUMENT_ID',
    headers: {
      Authorization: 'Bearer API_KEY_FROM_STEP1',
    },
})
```

Which yields the following error message:

```
Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

I've also tried xhr for the header, which also gives the same error:

```
$.ajax({
    method: 'GET',
    url: 'https://api.pdffiller.com/v1/fillable_template/DOCUMENT_ID',
    beforeSend: function(xhr) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + 'API_KEY_FROM_STEP1');
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Accept-Language', 'en_US');
    },
})
```

Any thoughts on where I'm going wrong?  Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Origin is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10143093/origin-is-not-allowed-by-access-control-allow-origin)

Comment: Thanks @Bert, but it seems like most of those answers assume I have control over the server, which I do not in this case.

Comment: Then you have to ask the owner of the site to allow you to do cross-domain requests.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add `CORS` headers to your request too, because you want to do a cross-domain request. Your requested `url` must allow `CORS` too, but because it is an API call, it should be allowed on their side ...

```
$.ajax({
    method: 'GET',
    url: 'https://api.pdffiller.com/v1/fillable_template/74275400',
    crossDomain: true,
    xhrFields: {
        withCredentials: true
    },
    headers: {
        Authorization: 'Bearer S1qAS0YFCfUbRemx2OGaeUcmm6mni1EXK3T1FkkL',
    },
});
```

Comment: That makes sense that I need to add CORS, but running the code above gave me the same error message :/

Comment: Well, it ssem that `api.pdffiller.com` not allow cross domain requests then. @Sean Are you sure you are allowed to use this api?

Comment: I guess I'll have to email them, but I have a paid account and an API key.  What would be the point of an API you can only make Curl requests on?

Comment: Browsers blocking it for security reasons. Others like curl ignoring it. @sjf125